# Parallel programming service on internet

Tags: parallel-processing

Here is my question:
Is tere any service or technology to run parallel algorythms on more computer without knowing them?

For example: I write a parallel algorythm. My friends install a simple client app, and if they have internet connection, they can help my calculation with their free processor capacity. I would like to see them like an additional core in my CPU.

If there is no technology like that, is there any unsolvable problems with developing one? (I know there must be a lot problems with code trasfering, operation systems, and compatibility)

Comment: Don't you think it's the same as Distributed Computing? You can search about it. For example MPI is a platform which enables you to write distributed applications.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can use [BOINC](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/) to set up your own *volunteer computing* project.  But I have no experience of this to report.